# Aspnet greedy route parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-routing

I have mapped route:

`routes.MapRoute("test", "/{p1:int}-{p2}", new { controller = "test", action = "int" });`

Such route should match int-string, like `/1-stuff`, and it works for such cases, however it does not work for `/1-stuff-stuff`. I guess this is because route is matched and then params are rejected because of int constraint.

If I remove constraints `p1` equals `1-stuff`, and `p2` equals `stuff`. Is there way to apply constraints in correct way or to mark p2 as "greedy" (but not catch-all), so `p1` equals `1` and `p2` equals `stuff-stuff`?

This is very important for making human-firendly urls, where ids are at front and everything is kebab case without additional characters.

Catch-all does not work for me I need p2 to be bound to action parameter. Regex does not help.

Comment: With slug like that it is usually advised to use the following pattern `/{id:int}/{*slug?}` similar to how StackOverflow does their URLs `/questions/50448520/aspnet-greedy-route-parameter`

Comment: Recently gave an answer along similar scenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50425902/add-text-to-urls-instead-of-int-id/50426483#50426483

Comment: I stated that I do not want catch-all parameters. I need routes like `/{id:int}-{greedy-text-param}/{other-greedy-text-param}`, also catch-all cannot be placed in middle (before other parameters).

Comment: You can also exclude the catch all `/{id:int}/{slug?}`. The problem with your current template is that the route table wont know which dash `-` to take. Including the id appended to the slug will cause problems to parse and match

Comment: There is enough information in route template. Id is marked as int so it should not contain any dashes, and from the other side there is slash/question mark/hash/end of url. I cannot use slug, because there are more identifiers, that should be bound to controller.

Comment: Can you add the additional information to the question so that part is clear. It will improve the question and its requirements.

Comment: You could also probably look at using a `regex` constraint to match the desired pattern. Just a thought.

Comment: I've already stated it in the question, but added it second time to be clear. Also regex is no different than int. This is not a problem with constraint itself, but with parsing of incoming uri.

Answer (score 0):

why not try something like ...

```
Routes.MapRoute(
    name: "test",
    url: "/{p1}",
    defaults: new { controller = "test", action = "int" },
    constraints: new { p1 = "^\d+-[\w-]*\.*$" }
);
```

... and then parse p1 inside your action

The regular expression might need a bit of adjusting depending on your requirement, but in this scenario p1 would be '1-stuff-stuff' then you can `split("-")` p1 to get your values